# How to capture Pano Videos on iOS?

Tags: ios, arkit

https://developers.google.com/vr/discover/360-degree-media

I have tried for 3 days trying to find something that records Pano videos without special hardware for my iOS app; Google 360 was the only thing I could find.

Has anyone used Google or anything else to capture 360 videos without special hardware? Is it even possible?

Any feedback on this will be greatly appreciated

Thank you

Comment: If you want to capture 360 degree video (as opposed to turning a panoramic image into a draggable still image) you will need a special camera. It isn't possible with the inbuilt camera

Comment: did you see the Google Media library? they claim it can record 360 video

Comment: Yes, using the Ricoh Theta camera.  The supported capture sources are listed under "media capture"

Answer (score 0):

You can capture 360° panoramic photos and videos with normal cameras if you have [6 of them](https://www.techyv.com/article/gopro-omni-6-camera-smarter-capture/). You need to arrange them into a cube so that each camera points 90° to the 4 others for which it is a neighbor. This will allow you to capture the equivalent of a [cube map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cube_mapping). You can convert a cube map to [equirectangular](http://www.jamesfmackenzie.com/2016/10/18/convert-equirectangular-projection-to-cube-faces/) (which is what most 360° editing software uses) using conversion software, or you can write it yourself if you're so inclined.

There also exist hardware extensions for the [iPhone that capture 360° equirectangular panoramas](http://www.threesixtycameras.com/best-360-camera-for-iphone-2017-update/). Some are reasonably cheap, and some are fairly compact.

For just photos, you can take the 6 shots with a single camera, but you need to align it correctly. There are [mounts to make it easier](http://benlo.com/GoPro/panorama.html).